# Remove a little gap between the nav and header

Tags: html, css

why there is a little gap between navbar and header when i make navbar  `display: inline-block;` and how can i remove this gap?
please check the code here...

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<header></header>
```

Comment: Can you make both the element display:block and check;

Comment: @SiluK we don't even need to make them block ... we simply need to remove the inline block and they are by default block and widith:100% and no whitespace

Comment: Inline-block actually gives you space. Unfortunately, you can't solve this. Try giving  block instead. and style accordingly.